# Mute sound if volume goes out of specific range?

Tags: windows-7

I'm looking for a program that will mute sound from specific app if its volume reaches value higher or lower than specified.

E.g. range is 10-20; if volume is 9 or less - mute; if 10-20 - unmute; if 21 or more - mute again.

Anyone?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: as @DavidPostill thsi is off topic if you wanted to go another route say you found a way but its not working how you wanted it to we may be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/133173/sound-muting-program-for-windows?rq=1 - "not offtopic"; http://superuser.com/questions/527940/program-sound-manager-for-kde - "not offtopic"; http://superuser.com/questions/329552/is-there-a-program-that-can-represent-functions-as-sound - "not offtopic". What decides that mine question is offtopic, and these are not?